# How to use the mouse scrollwheel to trigger a macro/service?

Tags: keyboard, automator, mouse, macos

I want to trigger "+" resp. "-" when I use the scrollwheel of my mouse (G700) together with CMD. Shortcuts triggered by key combinations only [are simple](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31496/how-to-create-a-simple-keyboard-macro-with-automator), but using the scrollwheel as the trigger seems to be more complicated.

What are my options to use CMD+mousescroll to trigger a key or service?

Answer (score 1):

One of the best apps that I have found that can do that is **BetterTouchTool**. It is free for MacOS 10.6+ It allows you to create links from all kinds of gestures, and button combinations. It works for the Magic Mouse, Normal Mice, Touchpads, Apple Remote, Siri Remote, Etc.

I was unable to get the cmd+scroll alone to work, but **cmd+shift+scroll** works great. To get it working: Install from https://www.boastr.net/ then open the app preferences and go to "**Normal Mice**" for gestures. "**Add New Button**" then Hold down the shift key as you scroll over the action area. (3) Make sure to check the Shift and the Cmd boxes.

Add a "**Custom Shortcut**" of + or -
You will have to create an entry for scrolling up and scrolling down separately.

[image: Adding Command Gesture in BetterTouchTool]

### Limiting The shortcut:

In the left panel "**Select Application**" you can have the Shortcut usable Globally or only apply if a specific app is active, ie. only work if you are in Chrome.

Advanced -- if you only want the shortcut to apply to a specific app you can setup a "Predefined Action" -> "Send Shortcut to Specific App" You can then Choose an app that receives the + or -