# Keyboard Shortcut to manipulate window position

Tags: macos, window-manager

I'm looking for a 'Bring all to back' command.

In fact, I'm using [Magnet](http://magnet.crowdcafe.com) and I have many superposed windows, and I would like to put the front window **A** to back in order to see the window **B** just below the window **A**.

Actually, I'm using Mission Control (https://i.stack.imgur.com/glvT2.jpg) to select the window **B** but I'm sure that is not the fastest way and I would like to create a Keyboard Shortcut to put the window **A** to back.

Any help will be much appreciated.

**Edit:**

I can resumed by: "How to put a window back of the screen" instead of the feature "Bring to front"

**Edit 2:**

Screen aspect:

[**Back** A B C D E F G **Front**]

Screen content:

- [] is screen
- A B C D E F G are windows
- A & C are from Finder
- B D F are from Safari
- E is from Notes
- G is from Reminder

Then:

1. G is **active**
2. Put G to **back**
3. Get F on **front**

So:

If I put successively G F E D C B A to **back** I will retrieve G on **front**

Comment: Are windows A and B of the same app or different apps?

Comment: @user3439894 different ;)

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use the default command-tab keyboard shortcut to toggle to the next app?

Comment: This is an extremely poor question! The simple answer to your A-B question is either cmd-tab (inter-app) or e.g. in the Finder cmd-~/cmd-< (intra-app - the shortcut depends on the keyboard layout and the app). But your question suggests ("I have many superposed windows,...") that app1 - appY have open windows windowA - windowX.

Comment: @klanomath Look at my scnd edit... I can't provide a better explanation

Answer (score 2):

### How to navigate macOS application windows like a boss

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> : switch to the **next app** (icon to the right)

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>, followed by <kbd>Cmd</kbd> <kbd>`~</kbd> : switch to the **previous app** (icon to the left)

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> <kbd>`~</kbd> : **cycle** through all open windows of the app in focus. (Minimized windows are skipped.)

Below is an animation demonstrating what it looks like when windows are cycled.

[image]

This is a much faster way to navigate than Mission Control. And if you use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd> to **Hide** applications you're not using, you can keep your workspace free of clutter. Hidden apps are revealed again when tabbed to.

<sub>This answer assumes the use of an English keyboard, where the back-tick key's shifted character is the tilde. On [non-English keyboard layouts](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201794), the back-tick key may have a different shifted character.</sub>

### Precision control

For those looking for a solution similar to Magnet, but free, you can customize the AppleScript below, place it inside of an Automator Service, and trigger it with a keyboard shortcut.

```applescript
tell application "System Events"
    set activeApp to name of first application process whose frontmost is true
end tell


set theApp to activeApp
(* These dimensions are for a 27-inch iMac. Customize as necessary. *)
set appWidth to 1280
set appHeight to 1440

tell application "Finder"
    set screenResolution to bounds of window of desktop
end tell

set screenWidth to item 3 of screenResolution
set screenHeight to item 4 of screenResolution

tell application theApp
    activate
    reopen
    set xAxis to (screenWidth - appWidth) / 2 as integer
    (*
    FOR LEFT PLACEMENT:   set xAxis to 0
    FOR CENTER PLACEMENT: set xAxis to (screenWidth - appWidth) / 2 as integer
    FOR RIGHT PLACEMENT:  set xAxis to (screenWidth - appWidth) as integer
    *)
    set yAxis to (screenHeight - appHeight) / 2 as integer
    set the bounds of the first window to {xAxis, yAxis, appWidth + xAxis, appHeight + yAxis}
end tell
```

<sub>Code originally written by [Amit Agarwal](https://www.labnol.org/software/resize-mac-windows-to-specific-size/28345/) and [Tetsujin](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/171738/123184). Combined and modified by me.</sub>

- [How to create a simple keyboard macro with Automator?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31496/how-to-create-a-simple-keyboard-macro-with-automator/31500#31500)

<sub>After triggering the Service, you may see the message: "AppName.app" wants access to control "SystemEvents.app". Allowing control will provide access to documents and data in "SystemEvents.app", and to perform actions within that app.</sub> You must click "OK" to use the Service.

Comment: It is best to include the Script itself here, I suggest. Also, There have been questions (and answers) for triggering a script with shortcut. Could you add one as link too ?

Comment: @ankii Good ideas. Done. :-)

Answer (score 1):

macOS is **not** Windows!. There is no universal shortcut which sends window A to the back and window C to the front assuming window A (front) and B (back) belong to app1 and window C (front) and D (back) belong to app2 to get the window sequence C - A - B - D finally. macOS' window management always "groups" windows of the same app and you will get the following sequence C - D - A - B (in this case executing <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>).

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you want to bring forward the next window of a specific application that is currently open.

Example:

- Three Finder windows are open in the same space
- Each Finder window is *not* minimized

Go to **System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Keyboard > "Move focus to next window"**. Click the Shortcut displayed to the right. Enter your Keyboard shortcut.

Now you can press your shortcut to cycle through your application's windows.

Comment: That's working if windows are from the same application. Here, windows  A and B are from different applications and B isn't on top of the screen but below A one. However, it's a good shortcut, tx :)

Comment: What about using CMD + Tab instead of Mission Control?

Comment: CMD + Tab will open the last used app's window. But I want the one below. Btw I supposed that if you can bring to front, there is a way to bring it back

Comment: @MrMojoRisin Pressing command-tab once brings the previously active app forward which should be the app window under the current app's windows. You might need to edit your question providing a better explanation and example of what you actually want then if this isn't it.

Comment: @user3439894 I can resumed by: "How to put a window back of the screen" instead of the feature "Bring to front"