# How to make Automator insert "AW" into a Stickies Note

Tags: automator

I tried using "Watch Me Do" in Automator to insert text "AW" and "Return" in a Stickies note. It recorded the following (Events were "Type 'AW'" and "Press Return", the rest is the expansion into code):

---

-- Type 'AW'

```
    delay 0.315949
    set timeoutSeconds to 2.000000
    set uiScript to "keystroke \"AW\""
    my doWithTimeout( uiScript, timeoutSeconds )
```

-- Press Return

```
    delay 2.538645
    set timeoutSeconds to 2.000000
    set uiScript to "keystroke \"
    \" "
    my doWithTimeout( uiScript, timeoutSeconds )

    on doWithTimeout(uiScript, timeoutSeconds)
        set endDate to (current date) + timeoutSeconds
        repeat
            try
                run script "tell application \"System Events\"
    " & uiScript & "
    end tell"
                exit repeat
            on error errorMessage
                if ((current date) > endDate) then
                    error "Can not " & uiScript
                end if
            end try
        end repeat
    end doWithTimeout
```

---

In System Preferences, Security & Privacy, Privacy I allowed Automator.app and Stickies.app to control my computer.

I saved the above example as a service and tried executing the service in an empty Stickies note.  Nothing happened.

I'm new at trying to use Automator.  This is such a simple action that I believe that I have misunderstood something.

If I add to the workflow an existing Automator action that launches the Stickies application, then "AW" does get inserted, followed by "Return".

Question [How to create a simple keyboard macro with Automator?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31496/how-to-create-a-simple-keyboard-macro-with-automator) shows a much simpler Applescript that could be adapted to doing what I describe (I've done such) but I'm frustrated that my simple "Watch Me Do" doesn't work.  What am I overlooking or not understanding?

Answer (score 1):

The **Stickies** app is not *scriptable*, meaning it does not directly support **AppleScript** via a **Stickies AppleScript Dictionary**, so most coding is going to use **System Events** and what's generally referred to as **UI Scripting** to manipulate the **Stickies** app.

The example *code* below, will do the following:

- *Open* Stickies.app and, or if already open, bring it to the front.
- *Create* a new Stickies note.
- *Move* the new note to the top left corner of the screen and set its size to the default size.
- *Type* "AW" and "return", with "return" simulating the Enter key being pressed.

---

```
tell application "Stickies"
    activate
    delay 1
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "n" using command down
    set properties of window 1 of application process "Stickies" to {position:{0, 23}, size:{300, 200}}
    keystroke "AW" & return
end tell
```

This **AppleScript** *code* can be placed in a **Run AppleScript** *action* in an **Automator Service** *workflow*.

---

**Note:** One of the drawbacks of **UI Scripting**, is at times the needed use of the `delay` *command* to ensure the *targeted* **UI Element** is available to be acted upon. You may/will need to either adjust the *value* of any `delay` *command* and or add/remove additional `delay` *commands* as needed/wanted through any given **UI Scripting** scenario. The example *code* above, as is, worked on my system. If need be, make use of the `delay` *command* and adjust its *value* as/where needed/wanted.

Also the above example *code* does not employ any form of absolute *error handling* and is meant only to show how the individual *events* can be coded to achieve the objective. The onus is always upon the User to add/use appropriate *error handling* as needed/wanted.

Comment: I accidentally edited this answer while copying, in edit mode, some of its content to another answer I was working on. I then pasted some code for the other answer into this one, however I've rolled it back to a proper answer. Sorry if this caused any confusion.